# Operating on multiple results from find command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find

Hi I'm a novice linux user. I'm trying to use the find command in bash to search through a given directory, each containing multiple files of the same name but with varying content, to find a maximum value within the files.

Initially I wasn't taking the directory as input and knew the file wouldn't be less than 2 directories deep so I was using nested loops as follows:

```
prev_value=0
for i in <directory_name> ; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    cd $i
    for j in "$i"/* ; do
        if [ -d "$j" ]; then
        cd $j       
        curr_value=`grep "<keyword>" <filename>.txt | cut -c32-33` #gets value I'm comparing
        if [ $curr_value -lt $prev_value ]; then
            curr_value=$prev_value
            else
            prev_value=$curr_value

        fi
        fi
    done
    fi
done       
echo $prev_value
```

Obviously that's not going to cut it now. I've looked into the -exec option of find but since find is producing a vast amount of results I'm just not sure how to handle the variable assignment and comparisons. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
find "${DIRECTORY}" -name "${FILENAME}.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 grep "${KEYWORD}" | cut -c32-33 | sort -nr | head -n1
```

We find the filenames that are named `FILENAME.txt` (`FILENAME` is a bash variable) that exist under `DIRECTORY`.

We print them all out, separated by nulls (this avoids any problems with certain characters in directory or file names).

Then we read them all in again using `xargs`, and pass the null-separated (`-0`) values as arguments to `grep`, launching one `grep` for each filename (`-L 1` - let's be POSIX-compliant here). (I do that to avoid `grep` printing the filenames, which would screw up `cut`).

Then we `sort` all the results, numerically (`-n`), in descending order (`-r`).

Finally, we take the first line (`head -n1`) of the sorted numbers - which will be the maximum.

P.S. If you have 4 CPU cores you can try adding the `-P 4` option to `xargs` to try to make the `grep` part of it run faster.

Comment: Fantastic, I was sweeping man pages to get the right flags. Provide an explanation of the pipeline (OP said he was new!), and you have my sincere vote :)

Comment: This is really helpful thanks. However I probably should have mentioned that the file that I need to parse is contained within multiple directories. I don't know if that makes much sense but I basically need to be able to search by date, i.e. /2013.04.07, /2012.* and /* need to be able to work if they are passed as parameters

Comment: Don't use `xargs` when you don't need it. This is shorter and better: `find "$DIRECTORY" -name "$FILENAME.txt" -exec grep "$KEYWORD" {} \;`. And why use the longer `${DIRECTORY}` style when `$DIRECTORY` is enough?